# Update column information for every process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, process, migration

After running a migration within an app:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.add_column :table, :column, :type
```

And updating the column information:

```
Model.reset_column_information
```

It appears that the column information is only updated for one process i.e Puma worker or Passenger process.

Is there a way to update it for every process without having to restart the processes like so ?

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Comment: I don't think so. The column information is cached in each class (the singleton class instance) and rails doesn't have a reference to class instances in other processes. Its not like you're running migrations often enough though that this would be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invent your own way to invoke column cache clearing in each process, for example a signal handler or a controller action action that will call that code. But in fact, better way is to restart, because other methods above go deep into your dependencies and thus lock them (you will not be able to easily change web server once you rely on its process model too deep).

Also keep in mind, that by bypassing rails migration flow your schema.rb will not reflect state of your servers.

PS. This looks like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), probably your actual issue is in your database design, so look again on it - migrations in runtime hint on non-optimal solution.